# Angular js `$scope.$id` value grows rapidly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

In the creation of every controller in my small application I print `$scope.$id` for debugging. I noticed that in every action that creates a new controller the `$id` grows by at least 50 and sometimes couple of hundreds.

Is this something to be worried about?

Comment: sounds like something that could be memory intensive. Could we see a few lines of code that does exactly this?

Comment: Sounds like every time the controller is printing `$scope.$id` it's running 5 times and maxing out each digest cycle, which the default max is 10. Could you post some code so I could see what's going on?

Comment: Sure but which code should I post? The class that wires controller and their views? A controller and it's html? The `$state.go('..')` statement that is causing the creation of a new controller and it's fitting html? I can't spot a specific suspicious block of code